# unable to initiate kubeadm in the controller node , It says port in use

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

sudo kubeadm init
I0609 02:20:26.963781    3600 version.go:252] remote version is much newer: v1.21.1; falling back to: stable-1.18
W0609 02:20:27.069495    3600 configset.go:202]

```
WARNING: kubeadm cannot validate component configs `for API groups [kubelet.config.k8s.io kubeproxy.config.k8s.io]`
`[init] Using Kubernetes version: v1.18.19`
`[preflight] Running pre-flight checks`
`error execution phase preflight: [preflight] Some fatal errors occurred:`
`[ERROR Port-10259]: Port 10259 is in use`
`[ERROR Port-10257]: Port 10257 is in use`
`[ERROR FileAvailable--etc-kubernetes-manifests-kube-apiserver.yaml]: `/etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-apiserver.yaml already exists`
`[ERROR FileAvailable--etc-kubernetes-manifests-kube-controller-manager.yaml]:` `/etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-controller-manager.yaml already exists`
`[ERROR FileAvailable--etc-kubernetes-manifests-kube-scheduler.yaml]:` /etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-scheduler.yaml already exists
`[ERROR FileAvailable--etc-kubernetes-manifests-etcd.yaml]: /etc/kubernetes/manifests/etcd.yaml already exists`
`[ERROR Port-10250]: Port 10250 is in use`
`[ERROR Port-2379]: Port 2379 is in use`
`[ERROR Port-2380]: Port 2380 is in use`
`[ERROR DirAvailable--var-lib-etcd]: /var/lib/etcd is not empty`
 [preflight] If you know what you are doing, you can make a check non-fatal with `--ignore-preflight-errors=...`
 To see the stack trace of this error execute with --v=5 or higher
```

Answer (score 4):

Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow.

**"Port in use"** means that there's a process running that uses that port.  So you need to stop that process. Since you already ran kubeadm init once, it must have already changed a number of things.

First run **kubeadm reset** to undo all of the changes from the first time you ran it.

Then run ****systemctl restart** kubelet**.

Finally, when you run **kubeadm init** you should no longer get the error.

**Even after following the above steps , if you get this error:**

```
[ERROR DirAvailable--var-lib-etcd]: /var/lib/etcd is not empty
[preflight] If you know what you are doing, you can make a check non-fatal with `--ignore-preflight-errors=...`
```

Then, remove the etcd folder (/var/lib/etcd) before you run **kubeadm init**.

**Note:**

1. This [solution](https://www.edureka.co/community/19089/error-while-doing-kubernetes-init-command) worked for other users.
2. The warning itself is not an issue, it's just warning that kubeadm no longer validates the KubeletConfiguration, KubeProxyConfiguration that it feeds to the kubelet, kube-proxy components.

Comment: it work for me. Thank

Answer (score 0):

I also got this issue, additionally i had to manually kill kubelet , using

$ pkill kubelet

kubeadm init worked without issues after this,.

Answer (score 0):

Seems cluster is not removed 100%.
Run below commands one by one. On all nodes of cluster. (Do not run all commands together).
After this try reinstalling cluster.

1. $sudo kubeadm reset
2. sudo apt-get purge kubeadm kubectl kubelet kubernetes-cni kube*
3. sudo apt-get autoremove
4. sudo rm -rf~/.kube